# How to edit image uploaded on the some box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

HTM like this :

```
<input type='file' multiple id="upload-file"/>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {

?>
    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>">
        <button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary show-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Javascript like this :

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
        for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
        }        
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
    var IsImgAdded=false;
    $('.img-container').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
            $(this).append(imgTmpl);
            IsImgAdded=true;
            $(this).find('.show-button').show();
        }
    });     
};

$(".show-button").click(function(){
    $("#upload-file").click();
});
```

Demo and full code like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1g8t-h5kn

I try like that. But it does not fit

Should when I edit image on the box 2, it will change image on the box 2. Not box 3

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a var to set the actual edited container than after the upload launch the function, check if the variable has a value different than null and append the img in the right place.

WORKING FIDDLE HERE: https://codepen.io/VLK_STUDIO/pen/wdQPRL

```js
$(function() {
  $(":file").change(function() {
    var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
    }
  });
});

var actualEdited = "";

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src=' + e.target.result + ">";
  var IsImgAdded = false;
  $(".img-container").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("img").length == 0 && IsImgAdded == false) {
      if (actualEdited == "") {
        $(this).append(imgTmpl);
        $(this).find(".show-button").show();
        IsImgAdded = true;
        return false;
      } else {
        $(actualEdited).find("img").remove();
        $(actualEdited).append(imgTmpl);
        $(actualEdited).find(".show-button").show();
        actualEdited = "";
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (actualEdited != "") {
        $(actualEdited).find("img").remove();
        $(actualEdited).append(imgTmpl);
        $(actualEdited).find(".show-button").show();
        actualEdited = "";
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}

$(".show-button").click(function() {
  $("#upload-file").click();
  actualEdited = $(this).parent();
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.show-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upload-file" type="file">

<div class="img-container">
  <div class="show-button">click
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="show-button">click
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="show-button">click
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="show-button">click
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try that code? When I uploaded the image, the image was not uploaded successfully

Comment: sorry there was one more token than needed, now it should work.

Comment: What are you changing? It's the same

Comment: If all the boxes are filled with pictures. And you try to edit it, it does not work

Comment: You're welcome, if you're interested on client img editing, take a look on this mini app. I've made it to help my client to build branded and edited images for their social network business profile. Canvas filters still to be not fully supported on all browser but you can find many interesting part of code. http://codepen.io/VLK_STUDIO/pen/JNveGx

Comment: Okay. If I have free time, I'll try it. But it does not seem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
        for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
        }        
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
    var IsImgAdded=false;
    $('.img-container').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
            $(this).append(imgTmpl);
            IsImgAdded=true;
            $(this).find('.show-button').show();
        } else {
           if ($(this).id == sessionStorage.getItem('blockid')){
            $(this).append(imgTmpl);
            IsImgAdded=true;
            $(this).find('.show-button').show();
           }
        }
    });     
};

$(".show-button").click(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('blockid', $(this).id);
    $("#upload-file").click();
});
```

You're forggeting to identify the edited blocks. I warn you this is not the best approach, but the faster one. Bind one object action to another is confusing and poor practice, i advise you to use better js functions/closures to get what you want with proper form.

Comment: Did you try that code? When I uploaded 1 image, all five boxes were filled up

Comment: this should append the image in the next free block as the actual script just do. If the first condition will be verified(and this happen if there are free blocks), the else part will be ignored.